# why will Mingw-w64 gcc compiler generate wrong warning about the format of %zd and %a

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings, mingw-w64

i am using gcc compiler and the command line is

```
{gcc 'hellowo.c' -o 'hellowo.exe' -Wall -g -O2 -static-libgcc -std=c11 -fexec-charset=GBK}
```

and the edtion infomation is

```
gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-win32-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
```

when I try

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float float1 = 64.25f;
    printf("%zd\n",sizeof(int));
    printf("%a",float1); //float1=64.25f
    return 0;
}
```

the compiler warns me:

```
hellowo.c: In function 'main':
hellowo.c:6:12: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]
     printf("%zd\n",sizeof(int));
            ^~~~~~~
hellowo.c:6:12: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
hellowo.c:6:12: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]
hellowo.c:6:12: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
hellowo.c:7:12: warning: unknown conversion type character 'a' in format [-Wformat=]
     printf("%a",float1); //float1=64.25f
            ^~~~
hellowo.c:7:12: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
hellowo.c:7:12: warning: unknown conversion type character 'a' in format [-Wformat=]
hellowo.c:7:12: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
```

however the output is

```
4
0x1.010000p+6
```

why this will happen, i am using a example of **C primer plus**  to study on my own

It is so strange that .exe can work well and my program can be compiled successfully.

i try modify %zd to %zu,("%zd" statement is a example of the **C primer plus**)

still have the warning:

```
hellowo.c:6:12: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' 
in format [-Wformat=]
     printf("%zu\n",sizeof(int));
            ^~~~~~~
hellowo.c:6:12: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
hellowo.c:6:12: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' 
in format [-Wformat=]
hellowo.c:6:12: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
```

why will Mingw-w64 gcc compiler generate wrong warning about the format of %zd and %a?

Comment: please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and show compilation commandline. Works fine for me using `gcc -std=c11` with gcc 9.2.0

Comment: also `gcc -v` output may be useful

Comment: Works for me with `gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)`

Comment: This isn't relevant to your problem, but the format for `size_t` is `%zu`, not `%zd`. A `%zd` format would be for the signed type corresponding to the unsigned type `size_t`.

Comment: So you are actually saying the program works correctly but generates bogus warnings during compilation?

Comment: emmmm,it autally generates  the wrong warning

Comment: What are the values of `__STDC__` and `__STDC_VERSION__`?   Try `printf("%d\n", __STDC__);` and then `printf("%d\n", __STDC_VERSION__);`.  This is _very_ helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is an incomplete answer.**

The `printf` function and the formats it support are not implemented by your compiler. They're implemented by the runtime library. In the case of MinGW, the compiler is a version of gcc and the runtime library is, if I'm not mistaken, the one provided by Microsoft for Windows.

The gcc compiler can also warn about `printf` format strings that it thinks are incorrect, for example if you try to use `%s` to print an argument of type `int`. It has to make some assumptions about what the runtime library supports. Typically it just follows the rules of the C standard. But with `-std=c11`, I'm surprised that it would complain about `%zd` and `%a`, which have been valid C since C99. (Some versions of Microsoft's runtime library might not support them, but that shouldn't affect the compile-time behavior.)

The bottom line is that your compiler has decided, for some unknown reason, that it doesn't recognize those formats, but the implementation of `printf` in the runtime library handles them correctly. There's a mismatch somewhere between your compiler and your runtime library. gcc is probably using some heuristic to guess that certain formats introduced in C99 are not supported, and it's guessing wrong in this case. Perhaps Microsoft updated its runtime library relatively recently and gcc hasn't caught up with the change.

The warnings shouldn't affect the behavior of your program once it's compiled and linked.

Incidentally, the correct format for a `size_t` value is `%zu`, not `%zd`, since `size_t` is an unsigned type. `%zd` is likely to work in this case, but use `%zu` anyway.

I'm able to reproduce the problem with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe` (version 7.4.0) under Cygwin. Removing the `-Wall` inhibits the warning.

You can avoid the problem by passing the option `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO` to gcc.  This causes it to use a different implementation for `printf`.

Comment: In the version I have installed (9.2.0),  `__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO` is only turned on by default if at least one of the following is defined: `_POSIX _POSIX_SOURCE _POSIX_C_SOURCE _ISOC99_SOURCE _XOPEN_SOURCE _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED _SVID_SOURCE`  .  Notably `_ISOC11_SOURCE` is excluded,  and the `-std=c99` flag does NOT cause gcc to set `_ISOC99_SOURCE`.  All makes no sense whatsoever to me but that's what we seem to be dealing with, IDK why they don't have the compiler default to not being broken and make people who want broken stdio provide a switch.

Comment: When i use the ```-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO``` option,program works well,no warnings,even if i use ```-Wall``` option , and the output became ```4```and```0x8.08p+3 ``` which is right

Comment: not an expert on floating point but I think `0x1.010000p+6` is actually the same as `0x8.08p+3` , just using a different  offset for display